# What is the meaning of 'it' and 'that' in the sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

There is an example of sentence below.

> What is it that you don't like about the subway?

And I'll give another sentence below.

> I don't like it when the subway gets really crowded.

In second example, what is the meaning of 'when' and 'it'?

Comment: The first thing you should learn by heart is to capitalize the first letter of the first word in a sentence.

Answer (score 0):

"It" can stand for a definite, obvious referent.

> I see the ball.   It’s over there.  Go get it and throw it back to me.

"It" is impersonal at times.

> It is raining.

Other times "it" stands for a condition rather than either of the two preceding cases.

> I hate it when I slam the door on my thumb.

This is what your sentences are referring to.

You have "it" standing in for a condition or for specific  circumstances.

"When" is only a way of connecting the condition to the feeling.

Comment: By the way, what about first example? Do you think that the example is correct in the aspect of grammar? I think that 'it' is object, and 'that' is conjunction. Then, Can we say that 'it' is demonstrative pronoun of explaining 'that clause'?

Comment: The first example is correct, natural English.

Answer (score 0):

Just as one example: reading the Wikipedia article on "impersonal verb" might help you with your question about "it" (but not entirely).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/139759)

Comment: @mdewey I took care to reply (partly) to the comment, by advising about how to learn about "impersonal verbs" (something the OP was clearly asking about, and had never heard of). I also criticised the question, validly, because it was not a fair question. But please re-read it slowly. I did provide a fair partial answer.